# How to store the result of a query in an existing column using PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
user

**id, name**, timestamp, place, time
```

the id with the name form the PK

I want to store the result of the following query in the time column which is already exist but contain no data

```
SELECT "time"(timestamp) FROM user as time
```

so if I had for example the following data

id: 1, name: Ann, timestamp: "2002-08-30 08:24:00", Place:US time:

and if if result of the following query

```
 SELECT "time"(timestamp) FROM user
```

is    08:24:00

I would like to store that in the time column and I want to do that for all the users in the table

I tried the following

```
SELECT "time"(timestamp) FROM user as time
```

but it only displays the result as an output and I would like it to be stored

is there a way to do that ?

thanks

Comment: Will both columns continue to exists or are you just migrating from a timestamp field to a time field? If you keep them both do they have to stay in sync or will the time field also sometimes have another value then the time part of the timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set the `"time"` of each row to the time-of-day of its `"timestamp"` then:

```
update "user" set time = timestamp::time;
```